# Check for invalid characters in a php string

Tags: php

How can i check to see if a php string contains only 0-9 , and |? so it would accept `158,147|157,541|145,157` but not `125 ,148|126,4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex:

```
if (!preg_match("~^[\d|,]+$~", $yourstr)) {
    // invalid
```

The regex explained:

- `~` is just the regex delimiter
- `^` is the start of string anchor
- `[...]` is a character class
- `\d` is a shorthand that means any character in the `0-9` range
- `|` and `,` are just the `|` and `,` literals.
- `+` is the "one or more" repetition operator
- `$` is the end of string anchor

It basically means:
Match a string that *only* has the following characters: `0-9`, `,` and `|`.

Change it to:

```
if (!preg_match("~^[\d|,]*$~", $yourstr)) {
    // invalid
```

If you don't want it to reject the empty string. The `*` means "zero or more" (instead of `+`, which is "one or more")

Regex Reference: http://regular-expressions.info/

Comment: it shouldn't reject an empty string