# Change dropdown value based on Text Input

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, input

I would like to change a select option based on the text input value.

For example, when typing mydomain.com, this should happen:

- I type "mydomain"
- I type "." (dot)
- It stops adding values to text input
- It searches for a select option with ".com" and select it

I have edited this old question of mine to make it clearer. This is a screenshot I had of that time, it might help illustrate the issue:

[image: Bug x Working version]

Code example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="domain" name="domain">

<select id="extension" name="extension">
    <option value=".com">.com</option>
    <option value=".com.br">.com.br</option>
    <option value=".net">.net</option>
    <option value=".org">.org</option>
    <option value=".info">.info</option>
    <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
    <option value=".tv">.tv</option>
    <option value=".name">.name</option>
    <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
    <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
    <option value=".blog.br">.blog.br</option>
    <option value=".flog.br">.flog.br</option>
    <option value=".vlog.br">.vlog.br</option>
    <option value=".wiki.br">.wiki.br</option>
    <option value=".adm.br">.adm.br</option>
    <option value=".adv.br">.adv.br</option>
    <option value=".agr.br">.agr.br</option>
    <option value=".am.br">.am.br</option>
    <option value=".arq.br">.arq.br</option>
    <option value=".art.br">.art.br</option>
    <option value=".ato.br">.ato.br</option>
    <option value=".bio.br">.bio.br</option>
    <option value=".bmd.br">.bmd.br</option>
    <option value=".cim.br">.cim.br</option>
    <option value=".cng.br">.cng.br</option>
    <option value=".cnt.br">.cnt.br</option>
    <option value=".coop.br">.coop.br</option>
    <option value=".ecn.br">.ecn.br</option>
    <option value=".edu.br">.edu.br</option>
    <option value=".eng.br">.eng.br</option>
    <option value=".esp.br">.esp.br</option>
    <option value=".etc.br">.etc.br</option>
    <option value=".eti.br">.eti.br</option>
    <option value=".far.br">.far.br</option>
    <option value=".fm.br">.fm.br</option>
    <option value=".fnd.br">.fnd.br</option>
    <option value=".fot.br">.fot.br</option>
    <option value=".fst.br">.fst.br</option>
    <option value=".g12.br">.g12.br</option>
    <option value=".ggf.br">.ggf.br</option>
    <option value=".gov.br">.gov.br</option>
    <option value=".imb.br">.imb.br</option>
    <option value=".ind.br">.ind.br</option>
    <option value=".inf.br">.inf.br</option>
    <option value=".jor.br">.jor.br</option>
    <option value=".lel.br">.lel.br</option>
    <option value=".mat.br">.mat.br</option>
    <option value=".med.br">.med.br</option>
    <option value=".mil.br">.mil.br</option>
    <option value=".mus.br">.mus.br</option>
    <option value=".net.br">.net.br</option>
    <option value=".nom.br">.nom.br</option>
    <option value=".not.br">.not.br</option>
    <option value=".ntr.br">.ntr.br</option>
    <option value=".odo.br">.odo.br</option>
    <option value=".org.br">.org.br</option>
    <option value=".ppg.br">.ppg.br</option>
    <option value=".pro.br">.pro.br</option>
    <option value=".psc.br">.psc.br</option>
    <option value=".psi.br">.psi.br</option>
    <option value=".qsl.br">.qsl.br</option>
    <option value=".rec.br">.rec.br</option>
    <option value=".slg.br">.slg.br</option>
    <option value=".srv.br">.srv.br</option>
    <option value=".tmp.br">.tmp.br</option>
    <option value=".trd.br">.trd.br</option>
    <option value=".tur.br">.tur.br</option>
    <option value=".tv.br">.tv.br</option>
    <option value=".vet.br">.vet.br</option>
    <option value=".zlg.br">.zlg.br</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this a question? If so, remove all the unnecessary code and post a SSCCE and what you have tried and where you are stuck rather than your whole page and two redundant images

Comment: I don't see the problem, it was all to better illustrate the problem and give a clear view about the issue

Comment: Well, I've elaborated a question and posted it here >.> Plus, I've searched a lot for a solution, but couldn't find

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this as the user types...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        //The user has typed something. See what they typed and split it.
        var value = $(this).val();
        var components = value.split(".");
        if(components.length == 2) {
            //They have typed a TLD like .com
            if($("#extensao option[value='."+ components[1] + "']").length > 0) {
                //They have typed an available TLD. Select the dropdown and update the box.
                $("#search").val(components[0]);
                $("#extensao").val("." + components[1]);
            }
        } else if (components.length > 2) {
            //They have typed a Second level domain like .blog.br
            if($("#extensao option[value='."+ components[components.length - 2] + "." + components[components.length - 1] + "']").length > 0) {
                //They have typed an available second level domain.
                $("#search").val(components[0]);
                $("#extensao").val("." + components[components.length - 2] + "." + components[components.length - 1]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Not sure if this was the kind of solution you were looking for (or something server-side). Either way you would need the additional server-side verification.

Comment: This is AWESOME! Exactly what I was looking for!!! It's almost perfect - It works perfectly with .com/.org/.net/.info/.biz - But not with .blog.br/.adv.br/.coop.br/.flog.br

Comment: @user2056484 I will check my code now, there might be an error.

Comment: @user2056484 I got the `components.length - 2`and `components.length - 1` the wrong way around, it's fully working now! Sorry!

Comment: You must NOT be sorry, this is perfect! I simply can't thank you enough for it!! Thank you a thousand times and have a blessed day!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas how to do

- Cut the ending ".tld" by parsing string.
- Ban "**.**" in input field. Button "search" will trigger the function that detects disallowed characters. If it finds any, it gets error. If everything goes fine, the result on second picture will be shown to you. More about this problem http://www.regular-expressions.info/ , or similar stack question [Check for invalid characters in a php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655362/check-for-invalid-characters-in-a-php-string)

Comment: I thought about using regular expression, but it doesn't looks good... I'm not familiar with parsing string. Any idea how to get to that perfect solution?

Comment: I advise you to get familiar with regular expressions. It is good in many ways such as validating input form. It is also your problem now. Please write some good regular expression validator accepting only letters, it gets rid off all potential problems with domains.
By the way the second solution is I think the best way to solve this situation.

Comment: I know I could use something like    `$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#domain').valid8({
     regularExpressions: [
      { expression: /^.+$/, errormessage: 'Please enter a domain.'},
               { expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9, \xBF-\xFF\.-]+$/, errormessage: 'Ops! Use only letters and numbers in your domain name'}
           ]
       });` but this is not a good looking solution :/

Comment: I'm looking for a code that solves the visitor problem instead of prompting a error message to him, just by ignoring extensions in text input for domain, it's not too hard, I don't know why you guys are bothering so much to help and negative me >.>

Comment: Imagine input like "lijšě534.řž687#řž!". How would you behave now?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php -- 
Returns TRUE if every character in text is a letter from the current locale, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I should use a regular expression to detect invalid characters, but not with the purpose to display error message if there's a domain extension in the input, you see the difference? I won't add "." to the regex, only accents and invalid characters

Comment: I'll add regex for invalid characters. I'm still left with the extension problem as displayed in the image @ question;

Comment: So if there's a dot, for example stackoverflow.com parse the string to "stackoverflow" and "com". First part check for letters (as I described above) and the second, if it's tld let it be. Then, use first part "stackoverflow" and add .com, .com.br, .net, .org and validate it. I hope this will finally help you ^^